# command line method to remove single line paragraphs from text file

Tags: sed, awk

I have a .txt file with two types of paragraphs:

> Some statements and numbers (02) and such followed by a return 
>   With some more stuff followed by two returns
>
> Then a single line paragraph that is followed by two returns
>
> Along with some more double line text return 
>   some more text.

I want to remove all single line paragraphs from the text file.  So that the result is:

> Some statements and numbers (02) and such followed by a return 
>   With some more stuff followed by two returns
>
> Along with some more double line text return 
>   some more text

I have been attempting to do this with sed and awk, but I keep running into problems coming up with a regex that will look for a newline followed by some characters and ending in two consecutive newlines \n\n.

Is there anyway way to do this with a one liner or am I going to have to write a script to read in line by line and determine the length of the paragraph and strip it out that way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk -F '\n' -v RS='' -v ORS='\n\n' 'NF>1' input.txt
```

- When `RS` is set to the empty string, each record always ends at the first blank line encountered.
- When `RS` is set to the empty string, and `FS` is set to a single character, the newline character always acts as a field separator.

[[read more]](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Multiple-Line.html)

Comment: That worked like a charm.  THANKS! I should've asked this 4 hours ago :) .  Can you explain a bit?  -F says record separator is a newline, and then printing if there are more than 1 newlines?

Comment: On some of my files, I ran into the awk 3000 byte record size limit due to some paragraphs being quite large (with no blank lines).  The perl method mentioned below did not run into this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to reach for Perl for paragraph-oriented parsing:

```
perl -00 -lne 'print if tr/\n/\n/ > 0'
```